# print out matrix by using android opencv

Tags: android, opencv

I'm learning opencv in android, I want to try out the Mat class by setting up a matrix randomly and print out its entries. But I don't know how to do so, I failed many times... I'm using an android pad and AIDE to do the program.

Could you help me by showing me an example? Thank you.

Comment: Only to be sure if I understood, you want to create a Mat with random values?

Answer (score 5):

```
Mat myMat;
//do u work on myMat

myMat.dump();//when you want to display the matrix
```

Comment: Thank you! I found this function really nice!

Comment: @Yiyangchen Accept is as answer if that all you need.